# R: how to set an if statement condition to only be triggered if whole column is equal to a value?

Tags: r

So let's say I have a list of data frames. Within each data frame, there is a column in which I want to create a new dummy column based on. This is how it works. For simplicity, let's just use vectors instead of a data frame in the example.

```
vect<-c(0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0)
```

In this case, the dummy column created would be as follows:

```
dummy_vect<- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

The dummy essentially occurs in the indexes only after the last value in vect. I have the code written to do this and it works without any issues. The big issue I'm running into occurs in the rare instance when all of vect is 0s

```
vect<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

For the context of the problem, when this case occurs, I need the dummy columns to be 1 at every instance.

How would I translate this into code? So if every value in vect is 0, return all 1s in the dummy column, else just do the code I've written that works for other cases. Any help is greatly appreciated! It might be something simple and I'm just really over thinking it, but I don't know how to set the if condition up properly at all

Answer (score 1):

Take absolute values, reverse the input and take the cumulative sum.  Finally change the 0 values to TRUE, reverse and convert to numeric.

```
vect <- c(0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0)

+rev(cumsum(rev(abs(vect))) == 0) 
## [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1

+rev(cumsum(rev(abs(0*vect))) == 0)   # 0*vect is all 0 input
## [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found a condition in an if statement that looks as though it is working.

```
if(all(df$x == 0){
df$dummy_col = 1
}else{
The code that does the process for all other cases...
}
```